# How to Import to Existing Class Parse

Tags: java, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

If I have a JSON file in the same format as the current class, how can I import the files so that they are **added** to the **existing** class?

[2 years ago](https://www.parse.com/questions/how-do-i-import-data-into-an-existing-class), Hector mentioned the feature wasn't available "*at the moment*". Has this feature been added since then?

Answer (score 1):

The current (at time of writing) online documentation says that you can only import when creating a new class. If you want to import new instances of an existing class you need to write your own script to process the JSON and use the REST interface to upload them.

Comment: Would REST be able to handle importing 40,000+ objects at a reasonable speed?

Comment: Define reasonable... Use the batch upload interface. I uploaded ~500 items in batches of 50 the other day and it took 15 seconds maybe (I didn't time it so the time is a guess but it didn't take long)

Comment: So 40,000 objects could easily be added within a day? I'm not too familiar with REST. Are there limitations from the Parse backend on number of imports/executed actions?

Comment: That has nothing to do with REST, your account has limits on API requests and request rate

Comment: I mean, when importing with REST, does that count towards API request usage? If so, each batch (in your example) would count as 1 request? Thanks for following up on the questions btw.

Comment: IIRC the batch is a convenience but it doesn't reduce the API request count (because it's unpacked when the server processes it) - so it would be 40k API requests